# print out content from my db threw a php function but it doesn't recognize the language (hebrew)?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

the output is a set of question marks the all the tables are encoded utf8_general_ci..

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with your question. Provide a code sample so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: $hotels = mysql_query($query);                                  $hotel = mysql_fetch_array($hotels);                            echo $hotel["content"];
/*content is the field i want to print*/ the output will be: ?????? ?? ??

Comment: it is just basic php don't know if it would help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the charset of the connection.
you do it like that:
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
add this code before your query.

anyway, you better use one of the newer data base extensions of php.
http://il2.php.net/pdo
or
http://il2.php.net/mysqli

Comment: No you don't. Using this method is explicitly discouraged in the PHP doc. See http://www.php.net/mysql_set_charset

Comment: works great !!! this site never fails of giving the right answers when you need them. thank's alot!